# Sublime 2 installing packages fails with SSL Exception tlsv1alert

Tags: ssl, openssl, sublimetext2, sublime-text-plugin

It's been some time since I used Sublime's package installer. I went to install a package today and find it fails with the following error in the console:

> ```
> Package Control: Error downloading package. HTTP exception InvalidCertificateException (Host codeload.github.com returned an
> ```
>
> invalid certificate ([SSL: TLSV1_ALERT_PROTOCOL_VERSION] tlsv1 alert
>   protocol version (_ssl.c:590))) downloading
>   https://codeload.github.com/seanliang/JavaPropertiesEditor/zip/1.1.2.
>       error: Package Control

This error occurs on every single package I try to install.

What is causing this error, and how can I fix it?

I am using:

Mac OSX
Sublime 2
Version 2.0.2
Build 2221

Answer (score 1):

Back in February of 2018, GitHub [deprecated older cryptographic standards](https://github.blog/2017-02-27-crypto-deprecation-notice/) on their platform, such that attempting to talk to any of their web API's using older versions of TLS results in an error. PackageControl uses an SSL connection to download packages (and refuses to talk to services that are not encrypted for safety reasons).

The error you're seeing here is a result of that change; the SSL support in older builds of Sublime can no longer communicate with GitHub because they can't negotiate a connection properly. This also applies to older builds of Sublime Text 3 as well; the issue was resolved in ST3 dev build 3158 and released to stable in build 3170 (Sublime 3.1).

Sublime Text 2 is no longer supported or updated and while most things still work, this is a case of something that won't. In addition on MacOS ST2 uses the system packaged python interpreter, which is problematic on more recent builds of MacOS where the Python version changed (e.g. packages may break unexpectedly).

Short of upgrading Sublime to a more recent build, the only recourse you have would be to manually install and/or upgrade the packages that you want to use.